# Hangfire CronExp to run 1 am on a specified day every month

Tags: cron, cronexpression, hangfire

I want to set up a cronExp to run 1 am  on a particular day of the month which is added from a query

```
cronExp = "0 0 1 "+@auto.Day+ "* *";
```

I tried the above but  I get this not syntactically correct

Please help

Update

I managed to make below work auto.Day =24

```
cronExp = "0 1 1 */"+@auto.Day+" *";
```

but it reads  Cron At 01:01 AM, every 24 days  is this the same as  01:01 Am on the 24th of everymonth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cron expressions can be tricky if you're not used to writing them. Check out https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12058_01/doc/doc.1014/e12030/cron_expressions.htm for an example of how to write them.

Yours would best be written as:

```
cronExp = "0 1 " + @auto.Day + " * * ";
```

Your first one didn't work because it was missing a space in the expression between the Day of Month and Month fields (it looked like `0 0 1 24* *`). Your second one was setting the minute, hence the 1:01 AM.

Answer (score 0):

Finally the expression below is what worked

```
cronExp = "0 1 " +@auto.Day+" * *";
```